# Find a Cartesian Equation for the Plane Satisfying Those Properties

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Find the Cartesian equation of the plan parallel to **j** and passes through the intersection of the planes described by the equations *x + 2y + 3z = 4*, and *2x + y + z = 2*.

I was able to get the parametric equation of the intersection line: (0, 2, 0) + t(1, -5, 3), but in this regard, there would not be any plane containing this line that is parallel to **j**, since this line itself is not parallel to **j**, correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

if the two given planes are $f=0$ and $g=0$ then any other plane sharing their line of intersection has equation:
$$
\lambda f + g  = 0
$$
this gives:
$$
(\lambda+2)x +(2\lambda+1)y +(3 \lambda+1) = 4\lambda +2
$$
to be parallel to the Y-axis we require the coefficient of $y$ to be zero, hence
$$
\lambda = -\frac12
$$
giving:
$$
3x - z = 0
$$

Comment: Nice! Would you please explain a bit more why the other plane has to have the form lambda f + g  = 0?

Comment: firstly, i should note that to keep things symmetrical the correct expression would be $\lambda f + \mu g=0$. however if $\mu=0$ we simply get the plane $f=0$, so i omitted this special case to keep the arithmetic as lucid as possible. now suppose the two planes were $x=0$ and $y=0$. their intersection is a line parallel to the $z$-axis which passes through the origin. can you see that any plane of the form $\lambda x + \mu y =0$ also contains this same line? conversely if a plane contains the z-axis its equation is the same as the equation of its line of intersection with the plane $z=0$. ctd

Comment: ...think through this simple case until you are convinced of the logic. now consider what happens if the original planes are $x=a$ and $y=b$. and finally suppose you apply a nonsingular linear transformation which changes direction of the axes and/or the angles at which they intersect

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the line is not parallel to $\textbf{j}$, but that's fine. There does exist a plane that both contains your intersection line and is parallel to $\textbf{j}$. To find this plane, we need a normal vector $\textbf{n}$ and an initial point. For the initial point, we can use the same initial point as the intersection line: $(0, 2, 0)$.

For the normal vector, notice that it must be perpendicular to any vector in the plane or any vector parallel to the plane. So we may take the cross-product $\textbf{n} = \textbf{j} \times \textbf{v}$, where $\textbf{v} = (1, -5, 3)$ is the direction vector of the intersection line.

Comment: Very helpful indeed! Thank you very much!